# INSERT INTO table2 SELECT FROM table1 then UPDATE table1 rows that selected/inserted

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, insert-update

I am writing a procedure to copy data from a table `data_entry` to another table `promotional`
Table structure of `data_entry` is as below (excluded non-related fields ) -

```
CREATE TABLE `data_entry` (
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `school_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pin` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_copied_to_promo` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`school_id`)
)
```

Table structure of `promotional` (excluded non-related fields )

```
CREATE TABLE `promotional` (
      `promo_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, //renamed to avoid confusion
      `school_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `mobile_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `city` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `pin` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `copied_school_id` INT, // edit - school_id of data_entry table will go here
       PRIMARY KEY (`promo_id`)
   )
```

Here is the procedure to copy all rows from `data_entry` to `promotional` where `is_copied_to_promo=0`.

Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uspCopySchoolsToPromotional`(IN param_insert_datetime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO promotional (
      school_name,
      mobile_number,
      email,
      website,             
      city,
      pin,
      copied_school_id                                   
    )
SELECT school_name,
    mobile_number,
    email,
    website,
    city,
    pin,
    school_id
FROM data_entry
  WHERE is_copied_to_promo =0 ;
END;
```

What I want to do now to update `is_copied_to_promo` to `1` in `data_entry` table for all the inserted/affected rows from above procedure so that each time I execute above procedure only new rows from `data_entry` table should copy to promotional.

I am calling this procedure via `PHP` code. The solution can be adding update query in the same procedure or run another query/procedue after executing `uspCopySchoolsToPromotional`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I forgot to mention that school_id in both tables are different. In promotional table data is coming from multiple sources. So I renamed the `school_id` with `promo_id` in promotional table to avoid your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied over the school_id as well then you have a unique key to work with, and you could then add an UPDATE after the INSERT to do this, like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uspCopySchoolsToPromotional`(IN param_insert_datetime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO promotional (
      school_id, 
      school_name,
      mobile_number,
      email,
      website,             
      city,
      pin                                   
    )
SELECT school_id,
    school_name,
    mobile_number,
    email,
    website,
    city,
    pin,
FROM data_entry
  WHERE is_copied_to_promo =0 ;

UPDATE data_entry 
    SET is_copied_to_promo=1 
WHERE 
    school_id=(SELECT school_id FROM promotional) 
    AND is_copies_to_promo=0;
END;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that school_id in both tables are different. In promotional table data is coming from multiple sources. One of them is `data_entry` table.

Comment: are school_name values unique?  if they are, you can match by that instead in the UPDATE WHERE clause :)

Comment: School name are not unique. But If I add a new column `copied_school_id` in `promotional` table and `school_id` of `data_entry` table will insert in it. In that case you may help.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql 8 was supposed to have Common Table Expressions but it doesn't seem to appear in the [release announcements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html), so you will have to use some other mechanism to implement this. One solution is to use an [after insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER data_entry  AFTER INSERT ON promotional_update
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE data_entry SET 
      WHERE is_copied_to_promo = 1 WHERE school_id = new.ID;
END
```

Another solution is to take a table level lock and update after the insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uspCopySchoolsToPromotional`(IN param_insert_datetime DATETIME)
BEGIN
   LOCK TABLES data_entry WRITE;
    ....


    UPDATE data_entry 
        SET is_copied_to_promo=1 
    WHERE 
        school_id=(SELECT school_id FROM promotional) 
        AND is_copies_to_promo=0;

    UNLOCK TABLES:
END;
```

Note that if you don't lock tables, you may find that race conditions result in inconsistencies. The two methods (trigger vs lock and update) have their pros and cons.

Comment: Going to try the trigger option and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow **Flauntster**'s query if you do not have School_id as auto_increment in both the tables.

if the column is auto_increment in both the tables, then you can follow below query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uspCopySchoolsToPromotional`(IN param_insert_datetime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO promotional (
      school_id, 
      school_name,
      mobile_number,
      email,
      website,             
      city,
      pin                                   
    )
SELECT school_id,
    school_name,
    mobile_number,
    email,
    website,
    city,
    pin,
FROM data_entry
  WHERE is_copied_to_promo =0 ;

UPDATE data_entry de
JOIN promotional p ON de.school_name = p.school_name 
    AND de.mobile_number = p.mobile_number 
    AND is_copies_to_promo = 0
    SET is_copied_to_promo=1;
END;
```

Hope this should solve your problem.